# What is the meaning and use of the sentence "C++ compilers use a binary object layout"

Tags: c++, pointers, object, memory, layout

While going through this C++ FAQ https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#cpp-objs-passed-to-c I encountered the statement

> Most C++ compilers use a binary object layout that causes this
>   conversion to happen with multiple inheritance and/or virtual
>   inheritance.

I could not understand the meaning and application of it. As per the C++ FAQ this object layout mechanism helps C++ compiler in the below mentioned check

> In C++ it is easy to check if a Derived* called dp points to the same
>   object as is pointed to by a Base* called bp: just say if (dp == bp)
>   .... The C++ compiler automatically converts both pointers to the same
>   type, in this case to Base*, then compares them. Depending on the C++
>   compiler’s implementation details, this conversion sometimes changes
>   the bits of a pointer’s value.

Could any one help to understand the **binary object layout** of any popular C++ compilers and what possible changes and the corresponding mechanism for **changes in  the bits of a pointer’s value.** and How it helps in comparing the pointers of Base/Derived classes.

Edit : Please explain why the below is also a valid statement.

> NOTE: you must be especially careful when converting both to void*
>   since that conversion will not allow either the C or C++ compiler to
>   do the proper pointer adjustments! The comparison (x == y) might be
>   false even if (b == d) is true:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, "binary object layout" means "how the binary data comprising the object is layed out in memory."

Consider this C++ code:

```
struct Left
{
  int ll;
};

struct Right
{
  int rr;
};

struct Derived : Left, Right
{
  int dd;
};
```

One possible way to organise these in memory (conceptually) is as follows:

```
+ Derived ----------------+
| + Left +  + Right +     |
| | ll   |  | rr    |  dd |
| +------+  +-------+     |
+-------------------------+
```

Of course, the class is just 3 `int`s, so with the above conceptual layout, the real layout would be just this:

```
+ Derived------+
| ll | rr | dd |
+--------------+
```

Now imagine this code:

```
Derived d;
Dervied *pd = &d;
Left *pl = &d;
Right *pr = &d;
```

`pd` points to the start of `d`, which is the same as the start of its `ll` member.

`pl` will point at the `Left` subobject of `d`. The start of `Left` is the start of the `ll` member. When comparing `pl == pd`, `pd` needs to be converted to type `Left*`. Remember that `pd` already points to the start of `ll`, so no change of the value of `pd` needs to happen. It's purely a conceptual conversion (a change of type).

`pr` points to the `Right` subobject of `d`. Since a `Right` object starts with the `rr` member, `pr` points to `rr`. Again, doing `pr == pd` requires `pd` to be converted to type `Right*`. The `Right` subobject of `d` starts with the `rr` member, but `pd` points to the address of the `ll` member. Threfore, the value (= bits) of `pd` must be *changed* by this conversion (incremented by the size of one `int`) to point to `rr` instead. Actually, exactly this conversion already happened once when converting `&d` from `Derived*` to `Right*` in order to initialise `pr` with it.

This should also explain why comparing in `void*` type doesn't work. Clearly, `&d.ll != &d.rr`, even though `pl == pr`.

Comment: How do I now handle a condition where I need to implement my own increment `++` operator needs to be overloaded for the above `structs`. Also can you refer to document something like C++ std etc.

Comment: Isn't that when we are using `&d` for all above assignments the address of `ll` will be assigned to each pointer type. Also why always `pd` has to be adjusted cant we adjust `pl` or `pr` or it is implementation defined.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza Derived-to-base conversion: C++11 4.10/3. Equality comparison: 5.10/1. But if you're still learning these concepts, you should probably be reading a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) rather than the C++ standard. It's the most authoritative source, but it's *hard* to read.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza And it's always the pointer to derived which must be converted to the type of pointer to base. The conversion which I talked about for `==` naturally also happens for the simple assignment `pr = &d`.